# Error while uploading Solr config and schema in DSE( CQL3 prepared statement failed after 4 attempts)

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I got error while uploading schema and configuration file byusing "curl" comment in centOS.

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images of error messages, it makes it harder for others to search for in the future.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/616644